# nscd uses 100% cpu

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

I'm working on a linux box and the output of `top` reveals that the command `nscd` (user `nscd`) is using 100% of CPU.

I'm uploading a flat file to MySQL from this box, and it is taking a long time (albeit it is a very large file)... I am curious whether `nscd` could be slowing it down by hogging all the CPU.

That said, I'm puzzled as to why anything could be working with a process taking 100% of CPU... because, after all, I am running bash scripts, perl scripts, and bash commands fine notwithstanding.

Is this a known problem with `nscd`? Is it actually hogging 100% of `CPU` as top reports?

Comment: No, it's not normal for `nscd` to peg a CPU core. Are you sure it's really `nscd` and not something disguised as it? What does `strace` show that it's doing?

Comment: I haven't used nscd in years as it's always caused numerous weird and system-breaking issues. One thing you can try is shutting nscd down, removing it's cache data (I think it's in `/var/lib/nscd/db` on most distros), and then starting it back up. That always seemed to get it working again.

Comment: I've experience similar issues, just restart it

Comment: The last time I saw anything like that was on a server that had more than a million users in /etc/passwd; it would do that when you added more users to it. If that's not the case here, I'll join the choir singing "restart nscd".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 7 years later, seems I found at least one condition when `nscd` shows suchlike behaviour - check whether you have space left on root partition.
Looks like, when there is no space left `nscd` uses all the file descriptors system provides and falls into condition of 100% CPU usage